# The directive is not detected from another file C#, .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, using-directives

I have a config file that contains all the configurations of my program. In that file, I define a directive as follow:

---------- MyConfig.cs ------------

```
#define TEST_LOCALHOST

public class MyConfig
{
   ....
}
```

Now, from another file (MyWebService.cs), I define a variable MyServerName based on the directive TEST_LOCALHOST is defined or not as follow:

---------- MyWebService.cs ------------

```
using MyData;

public class MyWebService
{

#if (TEST_LOCALHOST)
    private static string MyServerName = "http://localhost:8888";
#else
    private static string MyServerName = "http://MYSERVER";
#endif

}
```

The namespace structure in my program is:

```
| ----- WebService
| ---------------- MyWebService.cs
|
| ----- Data
| ---------------- MyConfig.cs
```

However, the TEST_LOCALHOST is always not defined in MyWebService.cs. I mean, my variable MyServerName is always pointing to "http://MYSERVER", but not to "http://localhost".

Am I missing something?

Comment: I suggest using a config file to determine the server name, instead of compiling it into your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx),

> The **scope** of a symbol that was created by using #define **is the file in which the symbol was defined**.

Because of this, it will not be beneficial to use a `#define` directive.
Rather use a property created in your `web.config` file and change the value of `MyServerName` according to that property

Comment: Bernd Linde gave a good answer. As he (almost) said, your case looks much more an application setting : I think it should not be handled as a compilation symbol!

Comment: I actually agree, this looks more like what the original user intended to do. But I just thought that since this code intended was to load testing strings, he didn't want to keep these 'symbols' visible in production code. Anyhow, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

To make sure it is located everywhere, I would either define this pre-processor switch in the project's settings itself (In Visual Studio, go to "Build" tab from the project's properties page and define the switch in the "Conditional Compilation Symbols" section); 
either define it the compiler switch on the command line with '[/define:name1[;name2]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx)'